# fetch rows using prepare statement not working

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm trying to fetch some rows from my DB but the problem is The code below doesn't give any type of error I'm getting an empty table with 0 errors.

```
 $query = "SELECT course_id,course_title,course_cord FROM courses  ORDER BY course_id DESC ";
        $run = $connection->prepare($query);
$run->bind_param('iss',$course_id,$course_title,$course_cord);
        $run->execute();
        $run->bind_result($course_id,$course_title,$course_cord);
        if(!$run){

          die("rip".mysqli_error($connection));
        }
       while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($run)):
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>{$course_id}</th>";
        echo "<th>{$course_title}</th>";
        echo "<th>{$course_cord}</th>";

        echo "</tr>";

        endwhile();
```

I'm really confused about this!

am I doing the fetch thingy wrong?

Comment: 0 rows may not be an error, simply nothing matches

Comment: @smith "Nothing matches" Explain please

Comment: its a select query, selecting based on a condition, in your case `WHERE course_id = ?($course_id)` if there is no row that matches that, you will get 0 results. that's not an 'error' that's "nothing matches"

Comment: @smith you are right! I removed the condition it works but I get this error  
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: well if you remove the `where` clause ,you are now binding 0 parameters

Comment: now you have 3 bound parameters, and are using 0

Comment: @smith thanks you really helped... you can put that as an answer